# Do Great General's effects stack in civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

I know Great Generals have this effect that boosts strength of nearby units.  If I have two GG set beside each other, do their effects stack?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A single unit can only benefit from the effects of one great general, even if more than one are within range.

Comment: If this was real life, two generals would cancel each other out.

Comment: Hehe.. The confusion would probably cause decrease in performance instead.