# Are Great Generals bonuses cumulative?

Tags: civilization-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Great General's effects stack in civ 5?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8762/do-great-generals-effects-stack-in-civ-5)

Great Generals give +25% bonus in battle. What about 2 of them? Are the bonuses cumulative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great General bonuses are not cumulative. A single unit may only benefit from a single great general at a time, though you may want multiple great generals *anyway*, to give more of your troops the bonus.

Comment: I now realize this is a duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8762/do-great-generals-effects-stack-in-civ-5

Comment: You can vote to close. Don't worry about me, I did it myself

Answer (score 0):

Great General bonuses are not cumulative. Combat bonus have a range of 2 hex tiles in all direction. Have more than 1 Great General only if you are fighting over a large battle theatre e.g. flanking a large enemy empire.